# In java how to merge two projects which have same sources but different root package

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I hava two projects, one root package is com.xxx..., another is org.yyy...

These two projects' codes are same but different root package such as:

one:

```
com.xxx.util
com.xxx.util.MyUtils.java
com.xxx.string
com.xxx.string.MyStringUtils.java
```

another:

```
org.yyy.util
org.yyy.util.MyUtils.java
org.yyy.string
org.yyy.string.MyStringUtils.java
```

Now I want to only write once in one of them, and update/merge in another, is there any way in gradle or maven plugins?

Comment: Why would you want to maintain two basically identical copies of the sources? Maybe it is easier to just have one copy and respective licenses (in case there are legal reasons).

Comment: I also cannot see any reason why you want to maintain the same project twice.

Comment: @Henry Because I need appropriate version, just like spring contains asm and cglib

Comment: @JFMeier Because I need appropriate version, just like spring contains asm and cglib

Comment: are you looking for something like this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: Henry is right. If you need a shaded version of your project, just maintain it _once_, but shade it for the other use case.

Comment: @Henry I want to generate code, shade seems is used in jar step